# Period of sum of periodic sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $m_t$ and $v_t$ be two periodic real sequences. Assume that for some constant $a$, it holds that
$m_t/a+v_t$ is periodic with fundamental period $k>0$. Is $m_t/b+v_t$ also $k$-periodic for any real number $b$? Moreover, is there any condition such that $k$ becomes its fundamental period?

Comment: Did you try any examples?  If, say, $m=\{(-1)^i\}=n$ then taking $a=-1$ we get $-m+n=\{0\}$ so the fundamental period is $1$.  Is that true for other constants $b$?

Comment: @Koro  Of course.  What's your point?

Comment: @lulu the fundamental period of a constant sequence is zero. But if it has zero as fundmental period, it is also $k$-periodic, for any natural number $k$.

Comment: The fundamental period of a sequence  $s$ is the least $k>0$ such that $s_n=s_{n+k}$ for all $n$.  Any sequence satisfies that with $k=0$, so that case is not considered.

Comment: @lulu I agree now. So a constant sequence is also $k$-periodic for all natural $k$. Right?

Comment: @CelineHarumi     Yes, that's correct.  If you prefer an example without a constant sequence, consider $m=\{1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,\cdots\}$ and $n=\{0,0,-2,-2, 0, 0, -2,-2, \cdots \}$ both periodic with period $4$.  With $a=1$ we get $m+n=\{1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2, \cdots\}$ which has period $2$ but for other constants $a$ we get period $4$.

Comment: @lulu Good example.